# PHP DOMDocument : how to select all links under a specific tag

Tags: php, domdocument

I'm just getting started with using php DOMDocument and am having a little trouble.
How would I select all link nodes under a specific node lets say

in jquery i could simply do.. $('h5 > a') 
and this would give me all the links under h5.

how would i do this in php using DOMDocument methods?
I tried using [phpquery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) but for some reason it can't read the html page i'm trying to parse.

Comment: could be usefull : http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, jQuery rewrites the selector queries to XPath. Any node jQuery can select, XPath also can.

`h5 > a` means select any `a` node for which the direct parent node is `h5`. This can easily be translated to a XPath query: `//h5/a`.

So, using DOMDocument:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//h5/a');

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
   // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Retrieve the [DOMElement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php) whose children you are interested in and call [DOMElement::getElementsByTagName](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.getelementsbytagname.php) on it.

Answer (score 1):

Get all `h5` tags from it, and loop through each one, checking if it's parent is an `a` tag.

```
// ...
$h5s = $document->getElementsByTagName('h5');
$correct_tags = array();
foreach ($h5s as $h5) {
    if ($h5->parentNode->tagName == 'a') {
        $correct_tags[] = $h5;
    }
}
// do something with $correct_tags
```