# Function is not working correctly in all situations

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have a function that I use to help me when scraping web pages for certain things (links etc.):

```
function list_tags($html, $start, $end)
{
    preg_match_all("($start(.*)$end)siU", $html, $matching_data);
    return $matching_data[0];
}
```

Example usage:

```
$open_tag  = '<a';
$close_tag = '>';
$links     = list_tags($html, $open_tag, $close_tag);
```

Thus `print_r($links);` results in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => <a href="blah.html">
    [1] => <a href="other_blah.html">
    Etc...
    Etc...
)
```

I can do the same thing when I use
`$open_tag  = '<script';` or 
`$open_tag  = '<div';` etc., but when I try to use `$open_tag  = '<input';` my array is completely empty, despite there being several `<input>` tags on the page. Any ideas?

**Edit:**

The particular page I'm trying to scrape on is `http://www.pcsoweb.com/inmatebooking/Inquiry.aspx`. I used the same thing on a page I made myself and it did find all the occurrences of `` `<input ... /> `` I had created.

I'll have to dig deeper to find out what is preventing me from grabbing the `<input />` tags on this particular site.

I'll also be looking into the `DOMDocument` class to see if this offers better results.

Thank you for the suggestions, **doublesharp** and **feeela**. I'll look into this a bit further to see what the real issue is.

Comment: Please post some snippet of your HTML input that contains some tags you want to match. Also, note that regular expressions are not the right tool to parse HTML. You should rather use a proper DOM parser.

Comment: To make your code more readable I would use `/` instead of parenthesis in your regex, and also make the matching group lazy instead of greedy - `"/$start(.*?)$end/siU"`

Comment: Yeah, please use some DOM parser to get specific elements. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514903/php-domdocument-how-to-select-all-links-under-a-specific-tag Tutorial1: http://www.binarytides.com/php-get-links-on-a-page-with-domdocument/ Tutorial2: http://www.stevenmcmillan.co.uk/blog/2011/php-get-page-links-using-the-domdocument/

Comment: Actually, looking it again you don't have proper delimiters between your pattern and modifiers - it needs to be the same characters and you are using `(` and `)`.

Comment: @doublesharp, incorrect: matched pairs like `( )` and `{ }` can be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a DOM parser is preferred, but if it's necessary to use regex to parse your data, try using `/` as your delimiter instead of `(` and `)` to make the code more readable and make your matching group lazy with `?` (remove the `U` modifier):

```
function list_tags($html, $start, $end)
{
    // escape forward slashes in your pattern start and end
    $start = str_replace("/", "\/", $start);
    $end   = str_replace("/", "\/", $end);
    preg_match_all("/{$start}(.*?){$end}/si", $html, $matching_data);
    return $matching_data[0];
}

$html = "<input test='test'><a href='asdf'>";
$open_tag  = '<(input|a)';
$close_tag = '>';
$links     = list_tags($html, $open_tag, $close_tag);
print_r($links);
```

Running this code results in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => <input test='test'>
    [1] => <a href='asdf'>
)
```

Comment: The `U` modifier actually reverses the greediness behavior, so you made it greedy!

Comment: Also, open and close parentheses can be used as delimiters.  It might not be the best style, but it will work.  The fact that the matching is successful sometimes argues against this being the problem.

Comment: +1 for getting rid of the _completely worthless_ (only-serves-to-confuse) `U` modifier.

Answer (score 0):

If I paste your regex `(<input(.*)>)siU` into http://www.functions-online.com/preg_match_all.html

with

```
<a>dfg</a><input type="sdgf"/>
```

One thing to take care with is inputs ending in `/>` (self closing). Something with your setup could cause that not to get found?

Without HTML sample, hard to say.